# How to write these queries in zend db

Tags: php

```
select test.*, 
       user.*,
       count(test_stats.test_public_id) as past_day_views,
       test_stats.test_public_id   
  from test 
  join user
  join test_stats
 where test.user_id=user.user_id 
   and test.test_public_id=test_stats.test_public_id
   and test_stats.updated_on > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
 group by test_stats.test_public_id
 order by title

select count(test_public_id) as total_views
  from test_stats
 where test_public_id ='$tourid'
```

These query for last week views retrieve as i don't much about again asking for this queries
Please do me this favor also

```
select count(ms.test_public_id) as total_views, ms1.recent_views from test_stats ms
join (select count(test_stats.test_public_id) as recent_views from test_stats
where test_stats.test_public_id = '$tourid' and test_stats.updated_on > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) ms1 where ms.test_public_id ='$tourid'

SELECT * FROM user WHERE activation = '0' AND user_id >1

select * from test where user_id ='$user_id' and test.url is not null
```

Comment: Seems to be a sql rather than a php problem. Additionally, some description about what you are trying to do and some formatting of the query would be very helpful.

Comment: Please see the Zend Framework Documentation at http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.select.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JOINS/WHERE is fundamentally incorrect.  I will fix that.  But in your model, create a function that does this:

```
class MyModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    // ...
    public function getSomeData()
    {
        $cols = array(
            'test.*',
            'user.*',
            'count(test_stats.test_public_id) as past_day_views',
            'test_stats.test_public_id'
        );
        $select = $this->select()
            ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
            ->from('test', $cols)
            ->join('user', 'user.user_id = test.user_id', array())
            ->join('test_states', 'test_stats.test_public_id = test_stats.test_public_id', array())
            ->where('test_stats.updated_on > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)')
            ->group('test_stats.test_public_id')
            ->order('title');

        return $this->fetchAll($select);
    }
```

And now for the second query:

```
$select = $this->select()
    ->from('test_stats', array('count(test_public_id) AS total_views'))
    ->where('test_public_id = ?', $tourid);

return $this->fetchAll($select);
```